# Git Move to New Remote Tool

Tags: git

Is there a tool that can automate moving (setting a new remote and pushing to it) git repositories from a Remote A to Remote B ?

**Requirements:**

- Configurable for mass moving
- Compilable or installable on Windows (7 64bit) or Linux
- Any Price

Comment: OS? Price? Read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information